# JSON.stringify and "\u2028\u2029" check?

Tags: javascript, json

Sometimes I [see](https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yI/r/-9bLNT3W5qB.js) in a view source page ( html view source) this code:

```
if (JSON.stringify(["\u2028\u2029"]) === '["\u2028\u2029"]') JSON.stringify = function (a) {
    var b = /\u2028/g,
        c = /\u2029/g;
    return function (d, e, f) {
        var g = a.call(this, d, e, f);
        if (g) {
            if (-1 < g.indexOf('\u2028')) g = g.replace(b, '\\u2028');
            if (-1 < g.indexOf('\u2029')) g = g.replace(c, '\\u2029');
        }
        return g;
    };
}(JSON.stringify);
```

- What is the problem with `JSON.stringify(["\u2028\u2029"])` that it needs to be checked ?

Additional info :

- `JSON.stringify(["\u2028\u2029"])` value is  `"["  "]"`
- `'["\u2028\u2029"]'` value is also `"["  "]"`

Comment: Related http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/07/25/the-json-specification-is-now-wrong/ and https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1907

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought it might be a security feature. FileFormat.info for [2028](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) and [2029](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm) have a banner stating

> Do not use this character in domain names. Browsers are [blacklisting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.IDN.blacklist_chars) it because of the potential for phishing.

But it turns out that the line and paragraph separators `\u2028` and `\u2029` respectively are treated as a new line in ES5 JavaScript.

From http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/07/25/the-json-specification-is-now-wrong/

> \u2028 and \u2029 characters that can break entire JSON feeds since the string will contain a new line and the JavaScript parser will bail out

So you are seeing a patch for `JSON.stringify`. Also see [Node.js JavaScript-stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005091/node-js-javascript-stringify)

**Edit:** Yes, modern browsers' built-in JSON object *should* take care of this correctly. I can't find any links to the actual source to back this up though. The [Chromium code search](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/ChangeLog&q=stringify&sq=package:chromium) doesn't mention any bugs that would warrant adding this workaround manually. It looks like [Firefox 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/ECMAScript_5_support_in_Mozilla) was the first version to have native JSON support, [not entirely](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=509184) bug-free though. [IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326893/is-json-stringify-supported-by-ie-8) supports it too. So it is likely a now unnecessary patch, assuming browsers have implemented the specification correctly.

Comment: Does the built in JSON object in browsers - already takes care of it for us ? and if yes - why do i need the check ?

Comment: I've added some additional details to the answer. In short, you probably don't need the patch in modern browsers.

Answer (score 4):

After reading both answers , here is the Simple visual explanation :

doing this

`alert(JSON.stringify({"a":"sddd\u2028sssss"}))` // can cause problems

will alert :

[image]

While changing the trouble maker to something else ( for example from `\u` to  `\1u`)

will alert :

[image]

Now , let's invoke the  function from my original Q ,

Lets try this `alert(JSON.stringify({"a":"sddd\u2028sssss"}))`  again :

result :

[image]

and now , everybody's happy.

Answer (score 1):

`\u2028` and `\u2029` are invisible Unicode [line](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) and [paragraph](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm) separator characters. Natively `JSON.stringify` method converts these codes to their symbolic representation (as JavaScript automatically does in the strings), resulting in `"["  "]"`. The code you have provided does not let JSON to convert the codes to symbols and preserves their `\uXXXX` representation in the output string, i.e. returning `"["\u2028\u2029"]"`.

Comment: If it is by default so why doing the check ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir To check the case if the functionality was already overriden.

Comment: Thanks. So the whole idea is to **preserve** the original meaning of those characters ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The whole idea is to preserve the `\uXXXX` representation for these characters. [#andyb has provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686687/json-stringify-and-u2028-u2029-check/#comment24013923_16686687) good links about why it is used -- looks like true.

Comment: Isn't that only a problem if your're using `eval` instead of being a good boy and using `JSON.parse`? It'd be correct then to say that it "breaks interpreting JSON as JS", not that it breaks JSON itself.

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, this is one more reason not to use eval. Presumably the check is to protect against people naively using eval anyway.